# regarding keep rows where one column value satisfy certain constraints

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There has a dataframe, one column, e.g., 'cost', have some zero/empty entries, I would like to keep the rows whose 'cost' column are not zero/empty. How to do it in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform two filters, first drop the nan values:

```
df.dropna(subset = ['cost'],inplace = True)
```

And then drop the zeros values as well:

```
df = df.loc[df.cost != 0]
```